# DocumentBuilder removes \n and \t while parsing the xml

Tags: java, saxparser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to keep whitespace before document element when parsing with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868887/how-to-keep-whitespace-before-document-element-when-parsing-with-java)

I'm trying to parse the xml so that i can replace the latin characters. latin characters within the xml is getting replaced, but \n and \t present within the xml are getting deleted. i'm using the dtd for replacing latin characters.
Below is the code i've used for parsing the xml

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        docFactory.setValidating(false);
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        docBuilder.setEntityResolver(resolver);
        String str = "";
        try {
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(is, contextPath);
            OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(doc); // Serialize DOM
            format.setIndenting(reqIndent);
            format.setOmitDocumentType(true);
            format.setEncoding(encoding);
            StringWriter stringOut = new StringWriter(); // Writer will be a
            XMLSerializer serial = new XMLSerializer(stringOut, format);
            serial.asDOMSerializer(); // As a DOM Serializer
            serial.serialize(doc);
            str = stringOut.toString();
        } catch (org.xml.sax.SAXParseException saxExp) {
            throw saxExp; // asString(is);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            throw e;

        } finally {
            if (is != null)
                is.close();
        }
        return str;
```

Comment: XML parsers will ignore leading and trailing whitespace in text between tags.

Comment: u mean parser will remove the tab space and white space characters ?

Comment: At the start or the end, yes.  There might be some way to turn this off, but it is normal for XML parsers.

Comment: do u know how we can retain it ?

Comment: have you tried to use the CDATA in the xml? http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp