# DOM Parser wrong childNodes Count

Tags: java, xml, dom, xsd, jms

This is strange but let me try my best to put it accross.

I have a XML which i am reading through the normal way from desktop and parsing it through DOM parser.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Abase
    xmlns="www.abc.com/Events/Abase.xsd">
    <FVer>0</FVer>
    <DV>abc App</DV>
    <DP>abc Wallet</DP>
    <Dversion>11</Dversion>
    <sigID>Ss22</sigID>
    <activity>Adding New cake</activity>
</Abase>
```

Reading the XML to get the childs.

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse("C://Users//Desktop//abc.xml");
Node root = doc.getElementsByTagName("Abase").item(0);
NodeList listOfNodes = root.getChildNodes();            //Sysout Prints 13
```

So here my logic works well.When am trying to do by pushing the same XML to a queue and read it and get the child nodes it gives me no. of child nodes is 6.

```
Document doc=docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(msg.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
Node root = doc.getElementsByTagName("Abase").item(0);
NodeList listOfNodes = root.getChildNodes();            //Sysout Prints 6
```

this screws my logic of parsing the XML.Can anyone help me out?

**UPDATE**

Adding sending logic :

```
javax.jms.TextMessage tmsg = session.createTextMessage();
tmsg.setText(inp);
sender.send(tmsg);
```

**PROBLEM**
 If i read this xml from desktop it says 13 childs, 6 element node and 7 text nodes.The Common Logic is :

- Read all the childs and iterate through list of child items.
- If node ISNOT text node get inside if block,add one parent element with two child and append to existing ROOT.Then get NodeName and get TextContext between the element node and push them as setTextContext for both the childs respectively.
- So i have a fresh ELEMENT NODE now which have two childs .And as i dont need the already existing element node now which are still the childs of root,Lastly am removing them.

So the above logic is all screwed if i am pushing the XML to queue and areading it for doing the same logic.

**OUTPUT XML** which is coming good when i read from desktop,but reading from queue is having problem, because it screw the complete tree.

```
<Abase
    xmlns="www.abc.com/Events/Abase.xsd">
<Prop>
<propName>FVer</propName>
<propName>0</propName> //similarly for other nodes
</Prop>
</Abase>
```

Thanks

Comment: `"C://Users//Desktop"` is a XML file?

Comment: Are those definitely exactly the same XML?  13 is the correct answer for the pretty-printed XML in the question (the six element nodes plus the seven whitespace-only text nodes around the tags), 6 would be correct if the XML were all on one line with no extraneous whitespace.

Comment: yes,exactly same XML the only difference is one am reading from desktop while the other am pushing to a JMS queue as Text Message and then reading it as ByteArrayInputStream.

Comment: OR i suspect ByteArrayInputStream is the culprit?? because i could see all the text nodes with the elemnts when i browse my queue.

Comment: tried  calling normalize() but no luck :(

Answer (score 4):

Well, there are 13 children if whitespace text nodes are included, but only 6 if whitespace text nodes are dropped. So there's some difference in the way the tree has been built between the two cases, that affects whether whitespace text nodes are retained or not.

Comment: ok,so is there any way i can preserve the white spaces when i push my xml content to queue and read it back.>>I wish to see 13 childs again so that my logic works,as the whole tree is changed my logic fails completely.

Comment: is there any way so that i can ensure the tree built in both cases should be same??

Comment: curious to know,how to keep xml tree similar across.

Comment: @user3560140 If you want help with that, then you should post the code generating and sending the XML to the queue. That said, I don't understand why your parsing is relying on blank text nodes.

Comment: @JBNizet:: blank text node >>  the text inbetween am using to create new element.The whole tree structure is changed so i can not manipulate it based on the type of the TextNode or ElementNode.

Comment: You need to provide runnable code that other people can try out to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MichaelKay:: Unfortunately i cannot add the complete code here only the snippet.Hope you understands.Would you please help in keeping the xml tree throughout.Is there any method for that.... Thanks for help :)

Comment: If I can't see the code with the bug in it then I can't help you find the bug.

Answer (score 0):

The document under "Output XML" means that there is something wrong on the sender side. My guess would by that `inp` isn't a `String` but some kind of object and `setText(inp)` doesn't call `inp.toString()` but instead triggers some kind of serialization code which produces this odd XML that you're seeing.

Comment: :: `inp` is a string and when am doing `tmsg.setText(inp);` this actually takes a string as input and then am simply pushing it to queue using the sender class, all is good till this point. But the real problem starts when I start reading the same xml back from the queue and at that time it is not considering white spaces and text nodes and only element nodes,so the tree built is different from what I have earlier pushed too queue. Thanks for help.

Comment: Show us the value of `inp` just before you call `setText(inp)`.

Comment: `here is the inp >Thanks for your interest< ` private static String inp = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
   "<Abase xmlns=\"www.abc.com/Events/Abase.xsd\">"+
     " <FVer>0</FVer>"+
      "<DV>abc App</DV>"+
      "<DP>abc Wallet</DP>"+
      "<Dversion>11</Dversion>"+
      "<sigID>Ss22</sigID>"+
      "<activity>Adding New cake</activity>"+
  "</Abase>";

Comment: How do you know that's the input? Did you check in a debugger or are you "just" sure?

Comment: I have not checked the input in debug, am trying to send a xml as a string input, so that is the way I have initialized my input strings.

Comment: My guess is that `imp` doesn't contain what you expect; hence the error. Use a debugger or some other way to look at the string you're actually sending. JMS doesn't change the data you send.

Comment: Out of my scope to understand :( that it is not the same string. Because that is just a string. It's not actually changing but tree built is screwed for some reason.