# How to avoid the trimming of these trailing whitespaces?

Tags: java, xmlbeans

I have a requirement according to which i need to send some trailing whitespaces(tabs) in the end of xml tag like below:-

```
<ImportFile Name="32201">Type   Action  </ImportFile>
```

I am using xmlbeans to set the value in tags:-

```
ImportFile importFile = importOption.addNewImportFile();
importFile.setName("Id");
importFile.setStringValue(value);
```

But by using above all trailing whitespaces get deleted and result in following structure:-

```
<ImportFile Name="32201">Type   Action</ImportFile>
```

P.S. I am not using pretty print XMLoption

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your text into a CDATA block:

```
<ImportFile Name="32201"><![CDATA[Type   Action  ]]></ImportFile>
```

As I know there isn't right way to preserve whitespaces in the XML
According to the [Annotated XML Specification](http://www.xml.com/axml/target.html#AVNormalize), whitespaces in attribute values are normalized by the XML processor.

This topic could also be useful for understanding parsing of whitespaces in the XML - [What You Need to Know About Whitespace in XML](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/wang-whitespace-092897.html)

Comment: Thanks Denis. Yeah I too thought of using CDATA but I need to adhere to guidlines given by client. :(

Comment: You could parse that xml with regexp and wrap such blocks with CDATA. Or you could write your own xml parser like here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/869050/1916536. But if a client doesn't follow standards you'll probably be doomed to do such workarounds forever. So I wouldn't silently do dirty hacks and would open discussion with a client at least to let him know about inconsistencies in his guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turned out that it was resulting in following structure only:-
Type   Action  
Actually to print the resulting element in docs i was using importFile.toString(). Instead of it printing as importFile.xmlText(), I found the actual result.